# create trigger on update to insert old values into other table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two tables. The first is  my person table which has id, name, creation_date as values, I have a  old_person table (id, name, modified_date) which I want to populate the value of person before it actually changes. How would I go about that? I have tried triggers but failed.

I tried as follows

```
create trigger Person_Trigger Update on person
before update
as
insert into old_person(id, name, modified) 
select id, new.name, getdate()
from person
```

It's giving me syntax errors...Not many Trigger references out there either, a little push would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the error?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following example

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e073/1)

IO hade a bit of trouble myself, but from [How to Create Triggers in MySQL](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/) there was a line that made me think

> *The first MySQL command we’ll issue is a little unusual:*
>
> DELIMITER $$
>
> Our trigger body requires a number of SQL commands separated by a
>   semi-colon (;). To create the full trigger code we must change
>   delimiter to something else — such as $$.
>
> *Finally, we set the delimiter back to a semi-colon:*
>
> DELIMITER ;

So in the SQL Fiddle I changed the query terminator to `GO` and that seemed top work.

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
  id INT,
  name varchar(20)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE old_person
(
  id INT,
  name varchar(20),
  modified DATETIME
)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER Person_Trigger before update on person
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO old_person(id, name, modified) 
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.name, NOW());
END
GO



INSERT INTO person VALUES (1,'TADA')
GO

UPDATE person SET name = 'FOO'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE TRIGGER `Person_Trigger`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `Person`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE date_modified datetime;

SET date_modified = NOW();

INSERT INTO old_person(id, name, modified) 
VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.name, date_modified);
END\\
```

This syntax works for me on my own projects. You may also need to declare delimiters before you begin the trigger. Also if you want to use the `NEW` keyword it should be `AFTER` update. Switch to the `OLD` keyword if you are going to keep using `BEFORE` update on your trigger.